# I have a line Break without <br>, why?

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to coding and I've got a small problem. I want to put 2 `<p>` on the same line but if I do that it won't work and show on other lines.

Why does it look like that and what can I do against it?

```css
.top{
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    background: url(bg/white.png); 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.title{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
}

.hometitle{

    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <p class="title">Lorem Ipsum</p> 
            <p class="hometitle">Home</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Because your text is in a paragraph <p> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Comment: A `<p>`aragraph is a natural break between blocks of text…

Comment: that's the purpose of `<p>` to be on different lines (parapraph). If you want this tag to behave like a span (although I don't see the point), you may add a CSS style with `display:inline`;

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paragraph

Comment: The class names you are using suggest you shouldn't be using `<p>` elements for this content at all (possibly an `<h1>` and an `<a>` (combined with some flexbox to put them on the same line) but its hard to tell what the right semantics to describe your content is.

Comment: Please go work through a couple of beginner’s tutorials that explain the absolute basics of HTML. This is not stuff you should be asking about here in the first place, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because default `display` of p tag is `block`.

If you want display one line, you can use `display: inline` or `inline-block`

[Paragraphs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) are block-level elements

By default, a [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block." This article helps to explain what this means.

```
 .title{
          display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 80px;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hometitle{
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```css
.top{
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    background: url(bg/white.png); 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.title{
      display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
}

.hometitle{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <p class="title">Lorem Ipsum</p> 
            <p class="hometitle">Home</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you very much. You're solution worked the best. But now it somehow ignores the text-align and it's just written on the left side. How can I fix that?

Comment: You should align at .top{ text-align:center;}

Comment: Works but now both are in the center, but I want the only the first one in the center and the second one on the right.

Comment: Finally worked! Thanks for helping out a beginner :)

Answer (score -1):

Only change this css

```
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything